# Order of Parameters in a POST in RestKit

Tags: ios, post, restkit

I have configured RestKit successfully so I can send out POST messages to the device I'm working with.

I have confirmed that when I use Chrome's Postman that the format of the message is correct.

I need to send......

id=87654321&content={"ts":1396215675,"payload":{"ssid_pass":"blah"}}&t=12345678

So in Chrome's postman, it goes out correct.  But when I use RestKit postObject

```
[manager postObject:self path:@"/tom" parameters:@{@"id" : K_IDVALUE,   @"content": myPayload, @"t":K_TVALUE, }  success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    NSLog(@"Successful Post!");
```

The order the device sees is wrong.  It sees

content={"ts":1396215675,"payload":{"ssid_pass":"blah"}}&id=87654321&t=12345678

The device really wants the content to be between the id and t tags of the POST request.  Is there a way to force RestKit to take the parameters as is?  It appears that the message is being alphabetized (which I assume is happening at serialization).

Comment: The server should not care about the order of the parameters. If it does, you might want to share the server code and we can take a look at that.

Comment: It's an embedded device (not a web server per se) and the ordering does matter in this case based upon the way the embedded programmer wrote it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to force RestKit to take the parameters as is?

What you are passing into RestiKit:

```
@{@"id" : K_IDVALUE, … }
```

is a `NSDictionary`, which has no concept of ordering of its elements.

Your only chance then is that RestKit is using the mapping you specify to determine the order of the keys. I cannot check now into RestKit sources to confirm this hypothesis, but you could just try it out (or simply verify what is your mapping current ordering).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  I will look into reading up on how RestKit does mapping and get back to everyone.  Appreciate it.